# android activities vertical transition animation

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation, transition

I don't know what is wrong here. Trying to make a vertical animation between two activities. Activity 1 should slide from being visible to bottom. Activity 2 should slide from top to bottom (become visible).

This is what I want
[image]

my code

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.top_to_visible, R.anim.visible_to_bottom);
```

top_to_visible.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
android:duration="300"/>
```

visible_to_bottom.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="-100%p"
android:duration="300"/>
```

what's wrong here ?

Comment: You said what you want, but you didn't say what you get :)

Comment: what I get is Activity one moves up + Activity 2 move up (I want the opposite and reversing the numbers doesn't solve it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible that you thought the y axis origin is at the bottom? Because when I just modify the from/to values I get what you want. The 0% of y is at the top. The 0/0 point is at the top left. So based on that you need the "to bottom" to move from 0 to 100% and the "from top to visible" to be -100% to 0%

top_to_visible.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toYDelta="0%p" />
</set>
```

and visible_to_bottom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toYDelta="100%p" />
</set>
```

Comment: Great ! and yes , I was understanding the XY coordination completely wrong :( THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Try this for visible_to_bottom.xml animation ..

android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="100%p"

remove the negative sign "-100%p" -> "100%p"

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `anim`. First create two xml files and put them in `res/anim`

top_to_visible.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0" />
```

visible_to_bottom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="100%p" />
```